# How to return null in all section in dictionary in python

Tags: python, fastapi

im using fastapi and python and need to check in dictionary if value is null.

i have a json like this:

```
{
 "id": null,
        "first_name": null,
        "last_name": null,
        "email": null,
        "user_id": null,
        "active": null
    },
```

using a query to DB.
my dictionary sting is

```
user = {"id": n['id'], "first_name": n['first_name'], "last_name": n['last_name'],
                  "email": n['a_email'], "user_id": n['user_id'], "active": n['active']}
```

this values *"active": null* is empty in the table. How i can use if-else in python to check, if unique_id is null i need to write in my json only
{null}

but if
*"unique_id": inc['a_unique_id']* have a value for example, 1, i need to get all info from this row:

```
{
 "id": 1 ,
        "first_name": "username",
        "last_name": "userlastname",
        "email": ""email@email.com,
        "user_id": userlogin,
        "active": 0
    },
```

final json i need to get should looks like this

--for row with info ---

```
{
     "id": 1 ,
            "first_name": "username",
            "last_name": "userlastname",
            "email": ""email@email.com,
            "user_id": userlogin,
            "active": 0
        },
```

for row with null values

```
{null}
```

i tried something like this

```
if n['id'] == "null":
            user = {"user": "NULL"}
        else:
            user= {"id": n['id'], "first_name": n['first_name'], "last_name": n['last_name'],
                  "email": n['email'], "user_id": n['user_id'], "active": n['active']}
```

but this dont work like i need

Comment: Try ```if n['id'] is None:``` instead.

Comment: json in this variant have only row with values. null rows are skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `None` is equivalent to JSON's `null`.

So what you should do is the following:

```
    if n['id'] is None:
        user = None
    else:
        user= {"id": n['id'],
                "first_name": n['first_name'],
                "last_name": n['last_name'],
                "email": n['email'],
                "user_id": n['user_id'],
                "active": n['active']}
```

Comment: it helps! but how i can get this null vallue not in massive?
i get now
"user": [  null  ], 
need to remove [ and ]

Comment: I've changed it to ```user = None```; but I'm not sure this is what you want.